# marionette compositeview onfetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am having a backbone marionette composit view as follow.

This is the initializing method.

```
initialize: function(options) {

        log.debug("Initialize");
        this.wizard = options.wizard;

        this.model = new Feed({
            id: options.modelid
        });
        this.modelid = options.modelid;
        this.collection = new Similar();

        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.onFetch);
        this.listenTo(this.model, "reset", this.onFetch);

        this.collection.fetch({ data: { id: this.modelid }});

        this.model.fetch();
    },
```

and this is the onFetch method

```
onFetch: function() {
        log.debug("Fetch");

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));}
```

and this is the append method

```
appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index) {
        log.debug("appendHtml");

        var jsonFeed = itemView.model.toJSON();

        if (this.prevFeed === null || jsonFeed.start !== this.prevFeed.start) {
            var date = new Date(jsonFeed.start);
            collectionView.$(this.itemViewContainer).append('<div class="day-divider c-color box-center" ><h3>' + moment(date).format('DD MMMM') + '</h3></div>');
        }

        collectionView.$(this.itemViewContainer).append(itemView.el);

        this.prevFeed = jsonFeed;
    },
```

My collection is emptied by the onFetch function that overwrites the html content.
this is my log:

```
DEBUG - Initialize
DEBUG - Render
DEBUG - appendHtml
DEBUG - appendHtml
DEBUG - appendHtml
DEBUG - Render
DEBUG - Fetch
```

any idea how this happen?
how can i resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use onRender instad of onFetch?
onRender is an already included function that displays content when render is done.

NOTE: You can even use onShow which does the job when everything has been rendered as well.

Comment: After a few thoughts I came to the conclusion that the method this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); } should be put in the render method ( overriding the backbone method ).